# Converter projeto em maven com EAR, qual melhor forma?

Tags: java, maven, arquitetura-de-software, jboss

[image: Estrutura do projeto]

Olá, gostaria de saber qual seria a melhor forma para converter esse projeto em maven para que ele possa reconhecer o "shared.war", "facede.jar" e ser empacotado como ".ear". Já fiz algumas conversões porém nunca com .EAR, poderiam me ajudar?

Grato!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voce pode usar o [Maven EAR Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/).

Desta forma, [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134894/maven2-best-practice-for-enterprise-project-ear-file) também há um outro post relacionado ao seu problema que pode lhe ajudar solucionar seu problema.